# Создание виртуального порта

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

У меня есть контроллер, который подключен по ip: 10.6.2.103
На контроллере есть UART, и чтобы подключиться к UART необходимо создать виртуальный порт,
там где надо указать скорость подключения. Т.е. если пытаться подключиться через putty, то
надо подключаться через serial port. То есть указать название порта и его скорость, все.

Я не знаю как это сделать.

Смотреть команду socat, но там связывают уже созданные два виртуальных порта.

То есть мой вопрос, скорее всего, звучит так: "Как создать виртуальный порт по Linux(Ubuntu)"

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под виртуальным портом? к uart надо подключаться через uart. и при чём здесь ip?

Comment: Скорее всего подключиться к uart можно по telnet или netcat без виртуальных портов.

Comment: Говорю контроллер, установлен удаленно, чтобы подключиться надо ввести его ip, ввожу, подключаюсь. Но, повторю, НО мне надо подключиться через uart, чтобы это сделать нужно создать вирутальный порт, потому что так и подключаются к удаленному устройству через uart, спрашиваю, КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ИЗ ip ВИРУТАЛЬНЫЙ ПОРТ?

Answer (score 0):

Короче Stack Overflow измельчал, пришлось потратить уйму времени, чтобы самому разобраться, вот решение: чтобы подключить удаленный uart порт через ip на Ubuntu в терминале надо ввести команду:

> sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUART,raw tcp:<IP-адрес удаленного
> устройства>:<номер порта>

, я ввел:

> sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUART,raw tcp:10.6.2.104:20108

, после чего через терминал открыл putty с правами доступа администратора (**sudo putty**, putty уже установлено, это сторонняя программа, которую можно запросто установить в Linux). И выбрав в putty пункт serial, в поле ввел /dev/ttyUART и поставил скорость 115200 и вуаля, все заработало.
Из ПО я поставил только пакет socat и putty как на винде. Попытался, без нагромождения программ.